# Swift is claiming there is no method in the class I am referencing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, spotify

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import AVFoundation
import AWSAuthCore

class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate  {
// Variables
var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
var session:SPTSession!

// Initialzed in either updateAfterFirstLogin: (if first time login) or in viewDidLoad (when there is a check for a session object in User Defaults
var player: SPTAudioStreamingController?
var loginUrl: URL?

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var loginSpotify: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setup()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateAfterFirstLogin()))


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func setup () {
    // insert redirect your url and client ID below
    let redirectURL = "splitter-app://callback" // put your redirect URL here
    let clientID = "client ID goes here" // put your client ID here
    auth.redirectURL     = URL(string: redirectURL)
    auth.clientID        = "clientID goes here"
    auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope]
    loginUrl = auth.spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()
    print("test")


}
func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.player == nil {
        self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.player!.delegate = self
        try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
    }
func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
        loginSpotify.isHidden = true
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
        let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
        let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
        self.session = firstTimeSession
        initializePlayer(authSession: session)
        }
    }
func initializaPlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.player == nil {


        self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.player!.delegate = self
        try! player?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)

    }


}



    }


func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
    // after a user authenticates a session, the SPTAudioStreamingController is then initialized and this method called
    print("logged in")
    self.player?.playSpotifyURI("spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp", startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("playing!")
        }

    })

}
```

}

The error is on line 31. Xcode says: Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'updateAfterFirstLogin', however updateAfterFirstLogin is in the class and should be able to be referenced. Why can I not reference it? Is it a problem with the NotificationCenter class that it cannot take a void function?

Thank you StackOverflow Community for reading my question! <3

Comment: This might be a typo in the question, but I think you're missing the closing bracket on your `initializePlayer` function.

Comment: You posted that before make sure every { is closed with }

Comment: it is because the `updateAfterFirstLogin` is inside `initializePlayer `. Format your code properly you will see it. The `updateAfterFirstLogin` function is not accessible outside `initializePlayer `.

Comment: @hardikparmar why don't you add that as an answer

Comment: @KevinPeterson Sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `updateAfterFirstLogin` is inside `initializePlayer` . Format your code properly you will see it. The `updateAfterFirstLogin` function is not accessible outside `initializePlayer`.

Also to use it with the `selector`, put `@objc` in the function declaration like this: `@objc func updateAfterFirstLogin()`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some brackets, I think:

```
func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
    if self.player == nil {
        self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
        self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
        self.player!.delegate = self
        try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
        self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
    }
func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
        loginSpotify.isHidden = true
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
        let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
        let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
        self.session = firstTimeSession
        initializePlayer(authSession: session)
        }
    }
```

add a } before func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {

Answer (score 0):

The selector argument receive selector object. This Object is obtective-C based object, so you have to add the @objc identifier before func.

correct your code (in the proper line) to:

```
@objc func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because misplacement of brackets. `updateAfterFirstLogin()` method is inside the  `initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession)` method. you need to use `}` after if statement in    `updateAfterFirstLogin()` like this:

```
func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
if self.player == nil {
    self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
    self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
    self.player!.delegate = self
    try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
    self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
} 
}
func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){}
```

After that you have to remove extra closing bracket from your code.